# How would I do a definition for a name validation

Tags: python, python-3.x, validation, definition

**What I want to do:**

I am trying to make a definition that takes an input (name as string) and checks if the name is in a set list.

If it is, the program will continue.
If it isn't, it will give the user 2 more chances to enter their name correctly.

**Requirements:**

I need to use the name variable after the definition.
I need the system to exit if the name is wrong 3 times.

**Problems:**

If the name is correct it works properly
However, if the name is wrong, it doesn't allow another name input, printing "You have 2 more tries" and "You have 1 more try" then ends the loop and exits.

**Code:**

```
names_allowed_to_play = ["MUM","DAD"]

def val_1 (name_1):

    print("Player 1, you have 3 tries to enter the correct name")
    print("")
    a = 0
    
    while a < 3:

        
        name_1 = name_1.upper()

        if name_1 in names_allowed_to_play:
            print(name_1 + ", you are authorised to play, have fun!")
            print("")
            a = a + 4
            names_allowed_to_play.remove(name_1)
            
        elif name_1 not in names_allowed_to_play:
            
            a = a + 1

            if name_1 not in names_allowed_to_play and a ==1:
                print("You have 2 more tries")
                print("")
                print("")
            elif name_1 not in names_allowed_to_play and a ==2:
                print("You have 1 more try")
                print("")
                print("")

    if a == 3:
        print("")
        print("Sorry Player 2, " + name_1 + " ruined it! " + name_1 + ", you are NOT AUTHORISED!")
        sys.exit()
        


#Run definition
name_1 = input("Player 1, please enter your name to play: ")
val_1(name_1)
```

Comment: You never seem to ask the user for new `input(). Also you have to return `name_1` from the function.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have fixed your code problem.

```py
names_allowed_to_play = ["MUM", "DAD"]
def val_1():
   print("Player 1, you have 3 tries to enter the correct name")
   name_1 = input("enter your name")
   a=0
   while a < 3:
       name_1 = name_1.upper()
       if name_1 in names_allowed_to_play:
           print(name_1 + ",you are authorised to play, have fun!")
           a = a + 4
           names_allowed_to_play.remove(name_1)
       elif name_1 not in names_allowed_to_play:
           a = a + 1
           if name_1 not in names_allowed_to_play and a == 1:
               print("You have 2 more tries")
               name_1 = input("enter your name")
               print("")
           elif name_1 not in names_allowed_to_play and a == 2:
               print("You have 1 more try")
               name_1 = input("enter your name")
           elifa == 3:
               print("")
               print("Sorry Player 2, " + name_1 + " ruined it! " + name_1 + ", you are NOT AUTHORISED!")
               exit()

val_1()
```

Comment: Please don't add code as images - they're not searchable and they're not accessible for those who have trouble reading.

Comment: iam new so when i tried putting code i was not able to put it .

Comment: Edit it and leave it in your answer and tag me / just comment here, and I'll clean it up for you. Usually you can use the `code` button in the editor to get it tabbed in by four spaces automagically.

Comment: I finally got it. I checked some info given by stack overflow. Thanks for helping me

Comment: "Here is working code" is almost never a *useful* answer, even if the OP can copy and paste it as is.

Comment: i was not trying to create advance code  I just solve the problem he was facing.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems with your code:

- you never ask the user for new input within the loop, instead just testing the first name again
- you modify the (local) `name_1` variable, but never `return` the value to the caller
- you do not have to repeat all the conditions, and can use math to determine the number of tries remaining

You can try something like this:

```
def get_name(player, tries, names_allowed_to_play):
    print(f"Player {player}, you have {tries} tries to enter the correct name")
    for i in range(1, tries+1):
        name = input("Please enter your name to play: ").upper()
        if name in names_allowed_to_play:
            print("You are authorised to play, have fun!")
            names_allowed_to_play.remove(name)
            return name
        elif i < tries:
            print(f"You have {tries - i} more tries")
        else:
            print("You messed up")
            exit()

names_allowed_to_play = ["MUM","DAD"]
name1 = get_name(1, 3, names_allowed_to_play)
name2 = get_name(2, 3, names_allowed_to_play)
print(name1, name2)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me, I think the way you had structured it meant the logic was flawed.

```
import sys, time

names_allowed_to_play = ["MUM","DAD"]

def main():
    authorised = False
    attempts = 3
    while authorised == False:
        if attempts < 3:
            print("You have",attempts,"remaining.")
        if attempts > 0:
            name = input("Player 1, please enter your name to play: ")
            name = name.upper()
        elif attempts <= 0:
            print("You are locked out.")
            time.sleep(1)
            sys.exit()
        if name in names_allowed_to_play:
            print(name," you are authorised to play, have fun!")
            names_allowed_to_play.remove(name)
            authorised = True
        else:
            attempts -= 1
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Major changes:

- put **input() in while loop** so you can get new input when the name is wrong, otherwise you only get the input once and the wrong name is checked by the if-statement 3 times
- add **return** statement for allowed name so you can use the name later (such as print out or other functions)

You can find other minor changes in my code comment.

```
# change the names to lowercase so you don't need upper() for input
names_allowed_to_play = ["mum","dad"]

def player_validate():
    # \n for new line, just works like your print("")
    print("Player 1, you have 3 tries to enter the correct name\n")
    tries = 0

    while tries < 3:
        player_name = input("Player 1, please enter your name to play: ")
        if player_name in names_allowed_to_play:
            print(player_name + ", you are authorised to play, have fun!\n")
            names_allowed_to_play.remove(player_name)
            # return will stop the loop so you don't need to break it by other code
            return player_name
        else:
            tries = tries + 1
            # use calculation instead of many elif statment
            print(f"You have {3-tries} tries.")

    # I have change Player 2 to Player 1, if it is not typo, you can change it back
    print("Sorry Player 1, " + player_name + " ruined it! " + player_name + ", you are NOT AUTHORISED!")
    # use exit() instead of sys.exit() or you will need to import sys at beginning
    exit()

# Run function (I think function is a more common name then definition)
name_to_use_later = player_validate()
print(name_to_use_later)
```